# How to update live tile (win 8 app) every 30min

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, tile, live-tile

How to update live tile (win 8 app) every 30min? (javascript)

I have function "UpdateIt()" and that update my tile. So question - how I can execute this function in background?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var changetitletimer = setInterval(function() { UpdateIt(); } , 1800000);
/* 1800000 is the value for 30min in milliseconds */
```

if you wish to stop it:

```
clearInterval(changetitletimer);
```